# Universal $C^*$ algebra generated by two self adjoint elements with $x^2+y^2=1+{(xy-yx)}^2$

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, c-star-algebras

Is there universal $C^*$ algebra generated by self adjoint elements $x,y$ subject to relation $x^2+y^2=1+{(xy-yx)}^2$?
What is a precise description of such algebra?

Comment: I think it's nicer to write this as $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ with $x,y,z$ all self-adjoint and $[x,y]=iz$.  One can check that in any representation by $2\times 2$ matrices we have $xz+zx=yz+zy=0$, and if we impose that relation then the monomials $x^iy^jz^k$ with $k\in\{0,1\}$ span everything, but I doubt whether that is too useful.

Comment: @Neil, your observation is very usefull because it shows that in any concrete representation of the above, one has that $\Vert x\Vert, \Vert y\Vert, \Vert z\Vert \leq 1$, whence the above relations are "admissible" in the sense of Blackadar [Shape theory for C*-algebras, Math. Scand. 56(1985), 249-275], and hence the *existence* of this algebra is guaranteed.

Comment: @NeilStrickland  Thank you  very  much  for  your  comment.  May  I  ask  you to elaborate your  comment(As  an  answer)?

Comment: @Ruy  Thank  you  very  much  for  your  comment. Could  you  please  more  explain on your  comments  or  add add an answer  to  my  question? To  be  honest  I  do  not  have  background  on "Universal  C*  algebra  associated to some  relation".